# Different ways to pass pointers to functions as arguments

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I can't understand why when i call a function like this:

```
typedef struct str_node{
    int data;
    struct str_node *next;
}node;

void begin(node *num);

int main(){

    node a;

    begin(&a);
```

I have to pass as argument `&a` and i can't pass simply `a`. Indeed when i have this situation:

```
void begin(node *head);

int main(){

    node *a;

    begin(a);
```

I have to pass `a` and not `&a`. But when i have this situation:

```
void begin(node **head);

int main(){

    node *a;

    begin(&a);
```

I have to pass again `&a` and not `a`. Moreover why I always have to use `node *a` instead of `node a` when I deal with the head of a linked list?

Comment: you need to learn pointers. We cannot replace a good C book. Read it, do all the exercises and you eventually will understand the difference.

Comment: I actually understood by writing the question itself, what I really didn't understand was only the last example, but by writing the question I understood.

Comment: On the first ones I know exactly the difference I just got confused. The difference is simply passing by value or by reference. Anyway, I'm not interested in convincing you of that. Good day.

Answer (score 0):

Visualize it with the following lines & corresponding comments:

```
int a = 5; // say, the compiler allocated 0xABCD0000 memory address for "a" 
int *b = &a; // say, the compiler allocated 0xDCBA0000 memory address for "b"

// memory layout so far;
// variable    memory address    value
// a           0xABCD0000        5
// b           0xDCBA0000        0xABCD0000

foo(a);  // pass the value of "a", which is "5".
// possible foo function decoration:
// foo(int x) {}
bar(&a); // pass the memory address of "a", which is "0xABCD0000"
// possible bar function decoration:
// bar(int *x) {}
baz(b);  // pass the value of "b", which is, in turn, the memory address of "a"
// possible baz function decoration:
// baz(int *x) {}

boo(&b); // pass the memory address of "b", which is "0xDCBA0000"
// possible boo function decoration:
// boo(int **x) {}
// you'll need the last one, if you want to change the address the pointer is pointing at in the sub-function "boo"
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to pass node *a when you want to make changes to the list, by passing the pointer to the list, the function will make the changes in the memory address of your original list. In the first case the funcion receives a pointer to a node. You initialized a node (node a) so if you want to pass a pointer to a structure you have to pass the address that points to node a by using & (&a). in the second case the function receives a pointer to a pointer to a node (double pointer) and you initialized a pointer to a structure (not a structure), so you only need to use & to get a double pointer.